# Plot linear and multiple linear reg on the same graph (ggplot)

Tags: r, ggplot2, lm

I have for instance this data frame :

```
data <- data.frame(
  x=c(1:12)
  , case=c(3,5,1,8,2,4,5,0,8,2,3,5)
  , rain=c(1,8,2,1,4,5,3,0,8,2,3,4)
  , country=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
  , year=rep(seq(2000,2003,1),3)

)
```

I would like to perform 2 linear regressions and plot them on one graph.
In a nutshell, I would like to compare the crude trend of cases over time (simple lm) with the same trend of cases but this time adjusted to rainfall over the years 2000 to 2003, on one and same graph.

```
model<-lm(case~ year, data=data)
```

the second one would be a multiple linear regression. I used this code for the purpose, but not sure it is ideal.

```
modelrain<-lm(case~ I(year +rain), data=data)
```

I did it with a simple plot with abline, but don't know how to make it with ggplot. I've created a new dataframe, but doesn't seem to work perfectly ( so I don't put the rest of my code here).

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you think `case ~ I(year +rain)` is doing? You just create a new variable `v = year + rain` and you perform `case ~ v`. Doesn't seem very useful too add the year to the rain variable. :-) Maybe you wanted to do `case ~ year + rain` ? Where you can get the coefficient of `year` when you control for the `rain` ?

Comment: Hi Antonio, I used `case ~I(year + rain)` by default. How can I plot the linear trend of the `case ~ year + rain` on the same graph than the simple linear regression ?

Comment: What do you mean "by default"? How do you expect your plot to be in the second case? You mentioned multiple linear regression, but the plot is going to have 2 axes (i.e based on 2 variables). Do you have a similar example somewhere else that you want to replicate?

Comment: I just wanted to have one graph showing first, the linear trend of cases over time (year - `case ~ year` and second, the linear trend of cases adjusted by rain over time (`case ~ year + rain`), to make the two graphs comparable.

Comment: Don't use `I()` because it tells R to literally use addition. Adding the year 2001 the rain value 8 to use 2001 + 8 = 2009 as a predictor is a bad idea, but that's what you are doing with `I()`. What Antonios suggests in comments (and the formula you show in comments) `case ~ year + rain` is appropriate, it just means use those two variables, don't literally add them like the code in your question does.

Comment: Also, please show your ggplot attempt. It is helpful to see what you tried to know where you are stuck and what you need help with.

Comment: Yes. Using `I` it's definitely not a good idea. I don't have a plot example to show you right now. I just wanted a graph showing the linear trend of cases over the different years ( `case ~ year`) and the second line ( on the same graph) the linear trend of cases but adjusted with rain.

Comment: I think the whole problem comes from the "adjustment" you have in mind. If you adjust (i.e. change/update) any of your variables `case`, `year` then it won't be possible to plot on the same graph as you'll have different axes. If you adjust your model (i.e year + rain) then your plot will ignore `rain` and the pattern between `year` and expected `case` values won't be linear.

Comment: You should do a regression by year, instead. And you'll be able to plot results by year and see if things changes as time goes by ..

Comment: @MrSmithGoesToWashington this is one option, but would be more appropriate if his initial model was `case ~ rain`. Another option is to split the `rain` variable to 3 groups (low, medium, high) and model `case ~ year` for each `rain` group. Another alternative is to first investigate a possible interaction between `year` and `rain` using `case ~ year * rain`...

Answer (score 0):

Building off the suggestions in the comments there are three valid regression models

```
model1<-lm(case~ year, data=data)
summary(model1)
model2<-lm(case~ year+rain, data=data)
summary(model2)
model3<-lm(case~ year*rain, data=data)
summary(model3)
```

With the limited data we have doesn't seem to be a lot going on.

The first question on how to plot the regression line for `model1` using ggplot is just:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=year,y=case)) + geom_point() + geom_lm()
```

As others have noted it is unclear what user3355655 means by "adjusted" for rain (since rain and year can't truly exist on the same x axis) but if we're willing to take the simplest course and simply treat rain as a "factor" then:

```
ggplot(data,aes(x=year,y=case,color=factor(rain))) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm",fill=NA) + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 10))
```